# I am trying to separate digits of a number and then store them in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to separate digits of a number and then store them in a list.
can someone please explain how the 'digits' line works?

Code:

```
n = [153,423,1,22]
for i in range(0, len(n)):

    digits = [int(d) for d in str(n[i])]
```

Comment: It's making an `int` out of every character in the result of `str` on a number...

Comment: google "list comprehension"

Comment: `n = [153,423,1,22]; n = [list(str(i)) for i in n]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. can you tell why is 'int(d)' there before 'for' ?

Comment: @Raghav it is a list-comprehension. If you just started learning, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Concentrate on the basics first. But go ahead an look up list comprehension if you are curious

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, thanks a lot and yes I have just started learning python.

Comment: While we are at it, please don't use `for i in range(len(n))`. Just use `for i in n` and if you need the index, use `for i, item in enumerate(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of learning a language is learning how to diagnose.  In this case, to figure out what's happening, you should "unroll" the loop in the list comprehension.  Then print values as the loop progresses.

```
n = [153,423,1,22]

for i in range(0, len(n)):
    # digits = [int(d) for d in str(n[i])]
    num = n[i]
    num_str = str(num)
    print ("Working on number", num_str)

    digits = []
    for d in num_str:
        digits.append(int(d))
        print ("Add digit", d, digits)
```

Does that give you some useful information?

Comment: Now it is clear. So, is it like list comprehension a short version of the one you showed?

Comment: To oversimplify, yes, a list comprehension includes the capability to put a `for` loop *inside* a list definition.  Get comfortable with the individual operations first; *then* look into list comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.